# displaying 2 toolbar problem in angular application

Tags: angular, angular-material, toolbar

I have an angular project in which I have 2 toolbar:
The first one is a fix toolbar for the whole application. I am putting this code inside a component toolbar:

```
<-- toolbar.component.css-->  
mat-toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

<--toolbar.component.html-->
<mat-toolbar>
   ...
</mat-toolbar>
```

The second toolbar is inside another component:

```
<--component.css-->
mat-toolbar {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

<--component.html-->
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
   ...
</mat-toolbar>
```

My problem is that the second toolbar is not rendered. the second toolbar shoud get rendered just after the fixed toolbar.

I am calling the two components inside my app.component.html

Could someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your developer console in browser. If it is having some error it might not have rendered. Also check if u have any *ngIf or hidden in your second component. If everything perfect then inspect the element and check whether that component is loaded.

Comment: don't have any ngfor inside toolbars. just two simple toolbars insered into two separate components. Also the two component are rendered. I think that the problem come from css because when I change the second toobar and add z_index and top=0 it get rendered on top of the first on

Comment: Usually Angular itself places the element one below the other so some of your css is causing the issue. Try removing all the custom css and check if it works properly